# Lodash Transform array of objects to array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have Array of objects like this:

```
[ { season: 1,
    episodes:
     [ 
       {
        title:'ep1 title',
        season:1,
       },
       {
        title:'ep2 title',
        season:1,
       },
       {
        title:'ep3 title',
        season:1,
       }] },
  { season: 2,
    episodes:
     [ {
        title:'ep1 title',
        season:2,
       },
       {
        title:'ep2 title',
        season:2,
       },
       {
        title:'ep3 title',
        season:2,
       } ] },
  { season: 3,
    episodes:
     [ {
        title:'ep1 title',
        season:3,
       },
       {
        title:'ep2 title',
        season:3,
       },
       {
        title:'ep3 title',
        season:3,
       } ] },
]
```

And I want turn it to array like this with loadsh:

```
[
  {
    title:'ep1 title',
    season:1,
  },
  {
    title:'ep2 title',
    season:1,
  },
  {
    title:'ep3 title',
    season:1,
  },
  {
    title:'ep1 title',
    season:2,
  },
  {
    title:'ep2 title',
    season:2,
  },
  {
    title:'ep3 title',
    season:2,
  },
  {
    title:'ep1 title',
    season:3,
  },
  {
    title:'ep2 title',
    season:3,
  },
  {
    title:'ep3 title',
    season:3,
  }
]
```

I just want to get episodes 
transform object to array with lodash
how to merge two arrays into a object using lodash
lodash: count values from array of objects

Comment: Not certain what Question is? Can you include the  `javascript` that you have tried  at OP?

Comment: By the way the output is *still* an array of objects. The subject or your question might be misleading.

Comment: @mfirry I know my mistake, What do you suggest for title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it really has to be lodash, you can use [`_.flatMap`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMap):

```
var flat = _.flatMap(data, 'episodes');
```

```js
var data = [ { season: 1, episodes:[{title:'ep1 title',season:1,},{title:'ep2 title',season:1,},{title:'ep3 title',season:1,}] },{ season: 2,episodes:[ {title:'ep1 title',season:2,},{title:'ep2 title',season:2,},{title:'ep3 title',season:2,} ] },{ season: 3,episodes:[ {title:'ep1 title',season:3,},{title:'ep2 title',season:3,},{title:'ep3 title',season:3,} ] },];

var flat = _.flatMap(data, 'episodes');

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

But JavaScript has since EcmaScript 2019 its own [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), so you can just do:

```
var flat = data.flatMap( o => o.episodes );
```

```js
var data = [ { season: 1, episodes:[{title:'ep1 title',season:1,},{title:'ep2 title',season:1,},{title:'ep3 title',season:1,}] },{ season: 2,episodes:[ {title:'ep1 title',season:2,},{title:'ep2 title',season:2,},{title:'ep3 title',season:2,} ] },{ season: 3,episodes:[ {title:'ep1 title',season:3,},{title:'ep2 title',season:3,},{title:'ep3 title',season:3,} ] },];

var flat = data.flatMap( o => o.episodes );
console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If `flatMap` is not available, you can use:

```
var flat = [].concat(...data.map( o => o.episodes ));
```

```js
var data = [ { season: 1, episodes:[{title:'ep1 title',season:1,},{title:'ep2 title',season:1,},{title:'ep3 title',season:1,}] },{ season: 2,episodes:[ {title:'ep1 title',season:2,},{title:'ep2 title',season:2,},{title:'ep3 title',season:2,} ] },{ season: 3,episodes:[ {title:'ep1 title',season:3,},{title:'ep2 title',season:3,},{title:'ep3 title',season:3,} ] },];

var flat = [].concat(...data.map( o => o.episodes ));
console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any special lodash functions - this can be done very easily with basic javascript array `.reduce()` like so:

```js
var oldArr = [{
    season: 1,
    episodes: [{
        title: 'ep1 title',
        season: 1,
      },
      {
        title: 'ep2 title',
        season: 1,
      },
      {
        title: 'ep3 title',
        season: 1,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    season: 2,
    episodes: [{
        title: 'ep1 title',
        season: 2,
      },
      {
        title: 'ep2 title',
        season: 2,
      },
      {
        title: 'ep3 title',
        season: 2,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    season: 3,
    episodes: [{
        title: 'ep1 title',
        season: 3,
      },
      {
        title: 'ep2 title',
        season: 3,
      },
      {
        title: 'ep3 title',
        season: 3,
      }
    ]
  },
]

var newArr = oldArr.reduce(function(result, current) {
  return result.concat(current.episodes);
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```